# Why does my LottieView animation flicker on first loop?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, lottie

I've just set up a new Lottie view animation as a splash screen for my react native project but on the initial loop of the animation, it flickers, but any times after that, it's fine.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

export default class LottieSplash extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <LottieView
        style={{ height: 180, width: 180 }}
        source={require('../../assets/splash.json')}
        autoPlay
        loop={false}
        onAnimationFinish={this.props.onAnimationFinish}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I only want the animation to play once then run a `navigation.navigate()` to a different screen. So if it plays once, it flickers but if I was to change `loop={false}` to just `loop` then the first play flickers and anytime after that, it's fine. However I do not want it to loop as I want to redirect once the animation has finished playing.

Here is a [streamable link](https://streamable.com/g8e0k3) to what it looks like.

Comment: Did you try with another animation json? In order to find out if it's the animation that causes the problem or something else

Comment: @dianaqqq I can't seem to try any of the other animations from lottefiles. It just crashes my app. I've tried a handful and it's all the same. The one I use now is a custom one which I made. I loaded it into the lottie files editor and there's no stutter/flickering there.

Comment: Okay, I've managed to get a lottie file to work that's not my custom one and it doesn't seem to have the same issue where it flickers. However, I'm not sure why mine flickers even though it doesn't flicker on the actual lottie file editor. Any ideas?

Comment: It's as if it's refreshing/flickering per frame of the animation but it only does it on the first occurence. Anytime after the first is fine.

Comment: Well when I encountered this issue, my problem was with the animation file (which was created by the designer) and I thought maybe it's your case too. I would try to set the autopay on false and set it after 1 second to true (with a setTimout) to see if it has something to do with this timing

Comment: @dianaqqq Thanks for responding but when I tried this out it didn't seem to work. I have however fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix my issue by updating my packages via `npm update`. I'm not actually sure what package caused this still but it seems to work now.